# Can tesserocr gives the spatial features(Location of text, bounding box etc..)?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I was trying to find the differences between the **pytesseract** and **tesserocr**. tesserocr will provide the bounding box details of the text same as pytesseract.

And what is the difference between the both libraries pytesseract and tesserocr?